# How to have my iPhone 11 iOS remind me of upcoming appointments?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, calendar, reminders

Is there a way for my iPhone to remind me of upcoming appointments and other things? I forget things all the time so i need to be able to jot down upcoming events to remind me as the time gets closer. If so, How do i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

**Calendar appointments** can have alerts.

> You can set an alert to be reminded of an event beforehand.
>
> 1. Tap the event, then tap Edit near the top right.
> 2. In the event details, tap Alert.
> 3. Choose when you want to be reminded.
>
>    For example, “At time of event,” “5 minutes before,” or another choice.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph3d110f84/ios

---

**Reminders** can have due dates. You'll be reminded at the time you choose.

> [image]
>
> Tap the date and time button  to set a due date for the reminder. Choose from Today, Tomorrow or This Weekend, or tap Date & Time to set your own day and time.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205890